# Auto-update process in the background

Tags: android, updates, auto-update, sony

Is there any way to schedule android app update from developers side, or to process update in the background (not closing/stopping the app)? I have an app, that could not be updated while it is working/playing, or at least the update has to be invisible and it shouldn't involve user's interactions (press to agree or sth like that)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to update an App while it is open. It have to be CLOSED for an update to happen.